Tiptap editor, dropped text turns into a link
I am having an issue with my Tiptap configuration.
I have a list of variables that I allow the user to drag into the editor.
At dragStart i transform the variable
variableElement.addEventListener('dragstart', (e) => {
            e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', `[${variable.value}]`); // Set the data to drag
        });

But for some of the variables like [dealer.email]
it turns dealer.email into a link for some reason.
But [dealer.zipcode] doesn't.
I am at a loss of why it transform some into links and not others.
Is there a solution?
